# Signing files with Azure Key Vault + AzureSignTool

Tags: azure, code-signing, azure-keyvault, code-signing-certificate, hsm

I have a program (**.msi file**) that is being built on a remote machine that I have no physical access to. The program is supposed to be distributed to users with Windows machines, however, in order to prevent the Smart Defender popup, I need to sign the installer with EV Code Signing certificate.

In order to implement the code signing on the remote machine that I am using right now, I was thinking about using Azure Key Vault along with AzureSignTool.exe, however, I am not sure whether this setup is reasonable. **Is there anybody who had any experience with such a setup and could let me know how well it works?**

I have also seen that in the Azure Key Vault there is a Managed HSM Pool option, however, I couldn't find much information on what that is. **Am I ever going to need that or can I just simply ignore it?**

Comment: I think this site would be useful:  https://seankilleen.com/2020/05/how-to-use-azuresigntool-to-sign-files-with-azure-devops-using-a-certificate-in-azure-keyvault/

Comment: Many thanks, @MattSmall! This link ensured me that the approach is right. Now the only question left is whether I am going to need the HSM Managed Pool?

Comment: I seriously doubt that you need an HSM pool.  These are typically used by institutions that need to store extremely secure cryptographic keys where they never leave that environment unless exported using very secure methods.  The institutions are typically government and financial.